# Partitioning and safely removing compact flash cards with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, removable

I have a set of compact flash cards with 2x NTFS partitions, which I need to work with via a USB compact flash adapter.

Windows XP and Windows 7 don't allow access to anything beyond the first partition if the   media is removable.

On windows XP this wasn't a big problem. I loaded a filter driver which made the compact flash card appear as fixed media. This allowed Windows XP to see both partitions. The drives and adapter still showed up in the "USB safe removal" list.

With Windows 7 this doesn't work so well. I can still load the filter driver and the cards show up as fixed media (or I can source cards which appear as fixed media in the first place) but they no longer show up in the "USB safe removal" list.

Any thoughts on how to get apparently-fixed media onto the "USB safe removal" list, preferably a one time only solution which doesn't require me to make a change for every brand of CF card I use?

Comment: Can you eject it via the "Devices and printers" screen? (*not* device manager; it's either on start menu or accessible via control panel) I guess it might not even be listed... but worth a glance.

Comment: @DMA57361: I tried this but the fixed device didn't appear on the "Devices and printers" screen.